# Creating indexes - MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

My "table" looks like this:

```
{'name':'Rupert', 'type':'Unicorn', 'actions':[
    {'time':0, 'position':[0,0], 'action':'run'},
    {'time':50, 'position':[50,0], 'action':'stoprun'},
    {'time':50, 'position':[50,0], 'action':'jump'},
    {'time':55, 'position':[50,0], 'action':'laugh'},
    ...
]}
```

Is there any way I can index the items within the actions list? Or do I have to split them up into further tables?

It would be a lot more convenient for me to keep the actions within the current table row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to **skot** in **#mongodb**!!

One solution is:

```
[...].ensureIndex({"actions.time":1})
```

for creating an index on the time field within the actions list.

Comment: given code is javascript, the actual method is 'ensure_index' in python

Answer (score 12):

Example for pymongo:

```
import pymongo

mongo = pymongo.Connection('localhost')
collection = mongo['database']['hosts']
collection.ensure_index('host_name', unique=True)
```

Comment: If you want to drop the duplicates: `collection.ensure_index('host_name', unique=True, drop_dups=True)`